# WCF, MySQL and Transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, .net-4.0

I am having a problem in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction in a Windows Communication Foundation Server Application.

I am using the MySqlTransaction inside the method of the class that implements the ServiceContract Interface and it throws this error when I try to run the service:

> **System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException**: Type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

My code in WCF service was simmilar to this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDALService
{
    MySqlCommand Command { [OperationContract] get; [OperationContract] set; }

    [OperationContract]
    void Execute(string cmdText);
}

[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class DALService : IDALService
{
    public MySqlCommand Command { get; set; }

    public DALService()
    {
        Command = null;
    }

    public void Execute(string cmdText)
    {
        MySqlCommand SQLCom = this.Command??new MySqlCommand();
        SQLCom.CommandText = cmdText;

        if (this.Command == null)
        {
            SQLCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SQLCom.Connection = new MySqlConnection(/* ... */);
            SQLCom.Connection.Open();
            SQLCom.Transaction = SQLCom.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        }

        if (this.Command == null)
        {
            try
            {
                SQLCom.ExecuteScalar();
                SQLCom.Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch { SQLCom.Transaction.Rollback(); throw; }
            finally { SQLCom.Connection.Close(); }
        }
        else SQLCom.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

The error occur just by typing the http://localhost:1257/DALService.svc in my web browser.

I am using Framework 4, code in C#, in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This either isn't your full Execute method, or this doesn't compile.  I don't see a return statement.  We should start with something that compiles.

Comment: I updated my question (change return type to void, and remove 'Result' variable inside try statement)

Comment: Is this the only method in DALService?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 (as well as all previous version *I've* worked on) have included a debugger... please use it before asking questions on SO because no one here is going to attempt to run your code for you unless you show some effort. Can you at least tell us which *line* the exception happens on?

Comment: I updated my question again (added all of my code). Sorry I'm just in the middle of developing that service, I cannot run it yet since I do not have codes to implement the service. But do you have any idea on why an error occur before even running any method on the service I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be the code that's causing an issue.  The error you are getting is coming from an attempt to return or pass in a MySqlTransaction to/from the service.  That's just simply not going to work.

Also, why on earth are you exposing a Command object to the outside world via a public property?  Furthermore, it doesn't even appear that you use it...  Delete that property and keep your command scoped to the method that uses it.  If you don't and you run this service as a singleton, you'll get lots of crazy bugs.

Even furthermore...  This is an extremely dangerous service to expose.  If you were to have someone use it other than yourself, it provides zero encapsulation.  Heck, you might as well just open up a port directly to the SQL Server, as dumb as that sounds.

Comment: I use it when I want to invoke the Execute method multiple times with only one connection, I rolled it back or commit it outside the service. So you are saying that I cannot pass the MySQLCommand in WCF?

Comment: No, you cannot.  It's not going to be serializable.  Anything that you pass into a WCF service has to be serializable.  Think about it, how do you represent a command object as an XML string( I know there other methods to serialize )?  The answer is, you can't.

Comment: I think your best bet here is to use a command pattern, and pass in those into the WCF service, then translate the commands into MySQLCommands on the server side.

Comment: You can but you absolutely should not.  This is an extremely dangerous service you are writing.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to create a command pattern. This service is only on local network and can only be used by the company employees. Thanks for answering.