# WCF TransactionScope doesnt RollBack

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

**I have used this guid: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/wcf-faq-part-5-transactions/
Why doesnt it rollback?? I dont understand!**

I have a service and client Application and I dont have a clue what is the problem with this code. 
after doing this line perfectly and save it in my DB,

```
proxy.AddEmployee("Stav", "20");
```

the next line throw Exception becouse I didnt send a number to the Age parameter, but the Transaction doesnt RollBack the first line so the Information : Stav, 20 still exsist in my DB!

```
proxy.AddEmployee("Stav123", "Not a Number(-->will do Exception)")
```

**EDIT 1:**
I add the AddEmployee implement.

client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.IJob proxy = new ServiceReference1.JobClient();
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                try
                {
                    proxy.AddEmployee("Stav", "20");
                    proxy.AddEmployee("Stav123", "Not a Number(-->will do Exception) ");//stop the running and show the Exception but keep the stav,20 in DB
                    ts.Complete();
                }
                catch
                {
                    ts.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

service:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IJob
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        void AddEmployee(string Name, string Age);
    }
public class JobImplement:IJob
    {
        [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
        public void AddEmployee(string Name, string Age)
        {
string strConnection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\WCF2\ConsoleApplication4\WCF_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        objConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Age) " + "VALUES ('" + Name + "' ,'" + Age + "')", objConnection);
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objConnection.Close();
        }
    }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WSHttpBinding Basic = new WSHttpBinding();
            Basic.TransactionFlow = true;
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(JobImplement), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
            //
            ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            //
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IJob), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Request123");
            host.Open();
            //
            Console.WriteLine("opened");
            Console.ReadLine();
            //
            host.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Add how is the AddEmployee method implemented ? Does it actually honor the transaction ?

Comment: I updated the topic with the implement. Anything else?

Comment: What binding are you using ? Not all bindings support transactions.

Comment: Ok that supports transaction. Do you have in your System.ServiceModel bindings section of the app.config trasactionFlow = "ture" ? aka. <binding name = “[your binding name]” transactionFlow = “true” />

Comment: I wrote it in my code. so no cofing needed. I will add the connection to my topic.

Comment: Your AddServiceEndpoint appears to be using a BasicHttpBiding in the code above. I do not believe that BasicHttpBinding is transaction aware.

Comment: what do you mean? what i need to fix?

Comment: Your call in Main, to host.AddServiceEndpoint, creates a new instance of the BasicHttpBinding class. I think you meant for it to us the local variable Basic instead, which you set to and instance of the WSHttpBinding class.

Comment: BasicHttpBinding doesnt support transactionflow. what do you mean? can you show me what am i doing wrong as anser comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a possible typo in your code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)         
{             
    ...
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IJob), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Request123");   
    ...
}
```

You are adding an endpoint of type BasicHttpBinding - a binding protocol that does not support transactions.

I am thinking that you actually meant to do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)         
{             
    WSHttpBinding Basic = new WSHttpBinding();
    Basic.TransactionFlow = true;  
    ...
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IJob), Basic, "Request123");   
    ...
}
```

That would give you a WSHttpBinding endpoint - a binding protocol that does support transactions.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I cant belive i was that stupid & i had 2 config files that i forgot to delete with BasicHttpBiding too.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement your own rollback function. Here's a basic way to do it. In your **Service** class interface add the `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]` attribute. Then add these codes:

```
private SqlCommand Command { get; set; }

[OperationContract]
public void BeginTransaction()
{
    this.Command = new SqlCommand();
    string strConnection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\WCF2\ConsoleApplication4\WCF_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    objConnection.Open();
    this.Command.Connection = objConnection;
}

[OperationContract]
public void RollBackTransaction()
{
    this.Command.Transaction.Rollback();
}

[OperationContract]
public void CommitTransaction()
{
    this.Command.Transaction.Commit();
}

[OperationContract]
public void CloseConnection()
{
    this.Command.Connection.Close();
    this.Command = null;
}

[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void AddEmployee(string Name, string Age)
{
    this.Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Age) " + "VALUES ('" + Name + "' ,'" + Age + "')";
    this.Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then you can access it in the **Client** code like this:

```
try
{
    proxy.BeginTransaction();
    proxy.AddEmployee("Stav", "20");
    proxy.AddEmployee("Stav123", "Not a Number(-->will do Exception)");
    proxy.CommitTransaction();
}
catch
{
    proxy.RollBackTransaction();
}
finally
{
    proxy.CloseConnection();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In all of the articles, the client was consist of transactionScope (In case I have more then one service-I was building an simple example that consist of one service, but in my next example I will add more services)- so the TransactionScope was managed all of this from the client so implementing my own transaction in the service is useless- (useless if I have more then one service -thats my goal) .btw, what is that: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)] ?

Comment: @StavAlfi [I dont think it's possible.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8982167/1115937) You at least need to pass a `Transaction` type to do that, but it is not serializable. And you also need a single connection in all your queries to attain what you need.